# Add readonly property to element if php session has special value

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I need to hide or make `readonly` two input fields based on who is logged in. If a specific user is logged in they appear, anyone else they don't. I can get the first part working and find the correct user. In the example I'm trying to make them `readonly`.

```
$user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
```

Then I get a bit lost trying various IF statements

```
if ($user == 'Jim') { 
    document.getElementById("notes").readonly = true;
    document.getElementById("coins").readonly = true;
}
```

This IF statement is what is causing nothing to work I assume.

```
<tr>
    <td><b>OFFICE USE:-</b></td>
    <td><b>Notes & Coins</b></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>Notes:-</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="notes"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Coins:-</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="coins"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you are mixing php with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing php (`$user`) with javascript (`document.getElementById...`). There's no real need to use javascript at all:

```
if ($user == 'Jim') { 
   $readonly = "readonly";
} else {
   $readonly = "";
}
// then, where you need an input to be readonly do:
?>
<input type="text" id="notes" <?php echo $readonly ?>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your condition code is incorrect because you can't combine javascript code with php code as you show. The javascript code should wrapped in `<script></script>`

```
<?php
if ($user == 'Jim') { 
    echo '<script>
    document.getElementById("notes").readonly = true;
    document.getElementById("coins").readonly = true;
    </script>'
}
?>
```

But it is better to add `readonly` property using php

```
<?php $user = $_SESSION['user_name'] ?>
<tr>
  <td><b>OFFICE USE:-</b></td>
  <td><b>Notes & Coins</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Notes:-</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="notes" <?php $user=='Jim' ? echo 'readonly' : ''?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Coins:-</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="coins" <?php $user=='Jim' ? echo 'readonly' : ''?>></td>
</tr>
```